# Trigger on form field when there is change in other form field angular5 form validation

Tags: angular2-forms, formvalidation.io, drupal-form-validation

I have an issue of triggering an error in a input form, if other form field is changed.

```
myFormGroup = new FormGroup({
            'name': new FormControl('', [ Validators.required ]),
            'material': new FormControl('', [ Validators.required, NumberValidator.isaNumber ]),
            'prefix': new FormControl('', [ ]),
        });
```

I want to alert the user to enter prefix field only when he changes the material field. Can someone help me with this.

Thank you

Comment: found a solution                                                                          myvalidators(control: FormGroup): ValidationErrors {
            if ((control.get('material').dirty && control.get('Prefix').value === '')) {
                return { 'prefix': true };
            }
            return null;
        }